WASD в Godot 4. как сменить клавиши управления
Я работаю над 2Д игрой с видом сверху, и сейчас нахожусь на этапе управления. Мне нужно что бы скрипт реагировал на нажатие клавиш A/W/S/D но стандартный шаблон управление настроен на стрелочки, а в подсказках мне ничего связанного с этим набором клавиш не выдают. Решил зафигачить свои функции которые использую в нужном месте. Но теперь я не знаю что мне писать уже в своих функциях...
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 250.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
func WASD_keys(delta):
    var key_x=Input.get_

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    var direction_y = Input.get_axis("ui_up", "ui_down")
    if direction_y:
        velocity.y = direction_y * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.y = move_toward(velocity.y, 0, SPEED)

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var direction_x = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction_x:
        velocity.x = direction_x * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()


Заглючил блок цитирования кода...

Так в туториале же всё описано https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html

Проект -> Настройки проекта -> Список действий -> Добавить новое действие: Пишете название действия, добавляете клавишу, в коде меняете вместо "ui_up" и остальных Ваше действие, можно назначать несколько клавиш на одно действие.

Проект > Настройки проекта > Список действий. Далее находишь ui_left/right/up/down и добавляешь бинды клавиш на эти комманды
